# Socket.io connection on server side does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Here is part of my app.js:

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000);//http.createServer(app);//app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("we are in connection");
    socket.emit('entrance', {username: req.session.user});
});
server.listen(3000);
```

I never get the console message on neither the terminal nor the browser(Which is pretty obvious)
Here is my client Side:

```
doctype html

html
  head
    script(type='text/javascript', src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
    script(type='text/javascripts', src='/javascripts/jquery.js')
    script(type='text/javascripts', src='/javascripts/client.js')
    script(type='text/javascripts')
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost')
        socket.on('entrance', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' })
        })

    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    title Chat Room
    body
    div#container
        ul#messages

    input(type="text",name="message",id='message_input')
    a#logout(href='/logout') Log Out
```

Comment: What do you use in the client script?

Comment: Are you looking in browser console or terminal console...also have you even started your app.js with the command `node app.js` ?

Comment: I have edited my post. Please Review. @Dave I of course am running the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the first three lines with:

```
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

And leave your `server.listen` line as it is.

Comment: Does the order matters?

Comment: As long as you define the variables before you access them, not terribly.